# Always Encrypted is not working for Where condition

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 to use always encryption option. I have 2 servers. I kept SQL Server 2016 in server and encrypted columns for my DB. I have hosted my ASP.NET MVC application on the other server using IIS. I am using Entity Framework to connect with SQL Server. I have added the column encryption setting=enabled; in my connection string.

I have also imported the certificate to the server in which my application hosted in IIS.

While running the below code, I am getting an error.

```
 var userName= context.testtable.Where(p => p.email == "melody@gmail.com").FirstOrDefault();
```

**Error**

> The data types varchar and varchar(100) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'testdb') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' are incompatible in the equal to operator.